# ERROR : Undefined name 'Firebase' in main.dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

Hello to whom it may concern,
I am setting up flutter environment in Android Studio and have searched to resolve this error but couldn't find any solution. The app I am working on has been registered with Firebase and I have copied all the code from flutter repo everything is fine except this one error where the keyword Firebase is not recognized. I have imported the targeted libraries but to no good.

Here is the line of code that has the error in main.dart:

await Firebase.initializeApp();

[The error reads "Undefined name 'Firebase'.  Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjXS9.png)

Your help would mean a lot! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you try importing firebase_core in main.dart
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing `firebase_core` for some reason.

Try adding explicitly to your `pubspec.yaml` and see if it helps.

```
firebase_core: ^1.0.1
```

Comment: I have added the dependencies previously. Here's what pubspec.yaml file dependencies states: 'dependencies:  
  flutter:                                                                             
    sdk: flutter  
  # Add the dependency for the Firebase Core Flutter SDK  
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+5  
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2

Comment: Remove your `pubspec.lock` file and try running `flutter pub get` again.

Comment: @miguel_ruivo Tried that still no luck. If you can kindly check the image since this is the only problem in the entire project structure. Perhaps you can help through this.  This is the link https://pasteboard.co/JS0nQKW.png

Comment: Tried that still no luck. If you can kindly check the image since this is the only problem in the entire project structure. Perhaps you can help through this. This is the link [https://pasteboard.co/JS0nQKW.png]

Answer (score 0):

not to use- firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
to use- firebase_core: ^1.4.0

not to use- firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
to use- firebase_analytics: ^8.2.0

not to use- firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
to use- firebase_auth: ^3.0.1

not to use- cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5
to use- cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0

changing versions helped me......
dont use versions mentioned on firebase documentation, use it from pub.dev